# ComboBox.Text not taking the ItemStringFormat property into account

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I just noticed a strange behavior which looks like a bug. Consider the following XAML :

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Page.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="data" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <sys:String>Foo</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Bar</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Baz</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
  </Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Button>Boo</Button>
      <ComboBox Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}}" ItemStringFormat="##{0}##" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=combo}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The `ComboBox` displays the values as "##Foo##", "##Bar##" and "##Baz##". But the `TextBlock` displays the selected values as "Foo", "Bar" and "Baz". So the `ItemStringFormat` is apparently ignored for the `Text` property...

Is that a bug ? If it is, is there a workaround ?
Or am I just doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug: `ItemStringFormat` is just a shortcut for "data template having a textblock bound to the value with the specified string format set in the binding". `Text` however is generally used when `IsEditable` is true and represents user-input. When you have anything other than strings in your list, it's preferable to use the `SelectedItem` than the `Text`. In any case, the following code will reapply the format to the text:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=Text, StringFormat='##{0}##'}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is a bit more complex... I need to retrieve the Text of the ComboBox in my ViewModel, so I use a binding with Mode=OneWayToSource. The ItemStringFormat I use is defined in the resources of the assembly containing the template, but the ViewModel is in another assembly, and can't access this resource... So I will have to duplicate this resource in the ViewModel assembly. I don't like that, but at least it will work...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably too late to help the OP, but just in case someone else stumbles across this...

The solution I would use to the real problem that the OP mentioned in the comment to the other answer is to use an `IValueConverter`.

Here's the code for the `FormatConverter` class:

```
public class FormatConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string format = parameter.ToString();
        return string.Format(format, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it (taken from the question with modification):

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">
  <Page.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="data" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <sys:String>Foo</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Bar</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Baz</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
    <local:FormatConverter x:Key="FormatConverter" />
  </Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}}" ItemStringFormat="##{0}##"
              Text="{Binding Path=VMProp, Mode=OneWayToSource, Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=##{0}##}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

This would cause the items to show up in the `ComboBox` as "##Foo##", "##Bar##", and "##Baz##" thanks to the `ItemStringFormat` being set to "##{0}##". Plus the `VMProp` property on the ViewModel would be assigned the values in the same format when they are selected thanks to the `FormatConverter` with the `ConverterParameter` being set to "##{0}##".

Please note that even though I used the `ComboBox.Text` property to remain consistent with the original question, I would suggest that the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property would be more appropriate. ;)